# Graph error: use r to change the axis limit

Tags: r, bar-chart

I was using r to draw barplot(grouped) of 50 states, and due to the date is from 2005-2012, so I want to change the axis limit. Here is the code.

```
b<-read.csv("/Users/tori/Documents/Curry/breach 2.csv")
br<-data.frame(b$State,
           e=b$Effective,
           f=b$First)
View(br)
bb<-t(br[-1])
colnames(bb) <- br[, 1]

View(bb) #ok
bd<-data.frame(bb)
par(las=1,mar=c(3,9,1,1),cex.axis=0.55)
barplot(bb,beside=TRUE,horiz=TRUE,xlim=c(2004,2011))
```

And turn out to be like this, I'm really confusing.
(I can't update picture, but it seems that the area out of the limit still have the graph.

> dput(head(bb))
>   structure(c(0L, 2006L, 2009L, 2006L, 2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
>   2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2007L, 
>   2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2007L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 
>   2006L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2008L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 0L, 2005L, 
>   2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2008L, 2006L, 2007L, 2005L, 2007L, 
>   2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2011L, 2006L, 2009L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 
>   2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2007L, 2006L, 2006L, 2005L, 0L, 2006L, 
>   2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2008L, 2006L, 2005L, 2006L, 
>   2005L, 2007L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 0L, 2010L, 2006L, 2005L, 2009L, 
>   2006L, 0L, 2007L, 2005L, 2005L, 2009L, 2005L, 2007L, 2005L, 2007L, 
>   2005L, 2008L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2008L, 2006L, 2006L, 2005L, 
>   2007L, 2009L), .Dim = c(2L, 52L), .Dimnames = list(c("e", "f"
>   ), c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", 
>   "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", 
>   "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", 
>   "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
>   "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
>   "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", 
>   "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", 
>   "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", 
>   "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
>   "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
>   "Wyoming")))

Comment: Please post `dput(head(bb))` so we can see what the data look like and what classes it is stored in. Just edit it into your question.

Comment: If the variable is either a Date or a factor variable, then you could be making incorrect assumption about what the 'xlim' argument is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change axis limits using `barplot(...,xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))`
Where `xlim` is for x-axis and `ylim` for y-axis.